# execute method after delay not using NSThread or sleep() - is there another option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is there a way in iOS4 to call a method after a delay using something else other than NSThread or blocking the UI using sleep()?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // code to be executed on main thread.If you want to run in another thread, create other queue
    });
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, I stumbled across it a few weeks ago and could not find it agin!!!

Comment: type dispatch_a and press ESC in Xcode, the autocomplete will kick in with this code :D

Comment: a beauty. thank you for this simple (and working) example). upvoted!

Answer (score 9):

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

Of `NSObject` will do this for you.

Additionally, you can create an `NSTimer` and have it perform a callback to some target and selector after a given amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can using [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). (for example `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats`)

Comment: If you value having to cancel the invocation of the method, i would say this is the best, as you can retain the NSTimer and invalidate on demand.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 
         selector:@selector(aMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void) aMethod:(NSTimer *) aTimer {
  //task to do after the delay.
}
```

Comment: Timer methods should take one argument; the timer passes itself in when it fires: `- (void) aMethod: (NSTimer *)tim;`

Comment: It works without it. But the API docs suggests to send the timer parameter. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```